# Algolia Autocomplete renderer Nexjts cannot access the next/router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, algolia

We are currently implementing an Algolia AutoComplete search using the AutoComplete with React tools Algolia provide.

Link to documentation for reference:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/integrations/using-react/

What we have noticed is that once we had implemeted the following renderer according to documentation:

```js
import { autocomplete } from '@algolia/autocomplete-js';
import React, { createElement, Fragment, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export function Autocomplete(props) {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!containerRef.current) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const search = autocomplete({
      container: containerRef.current,
      renderer: { createElement, Fragment },
      render({ children }, root) {
        render(children, root);
      },
      ...props,
    });

    return () => {
      search.destroy();
    };
  }, [props]);

  return <div ref={containerRef} />;
}
```

Every element rendered by it would no longer have access to the NextJs router hooks. So using any NextJs provided component would break the render cycle.

Which is not ideal, since we would want to use the `next/link` and `next/router` to enable internal client side routing.

We have tried wrapping the renderer with a `withRouter` but the same issue persists.

We also have a lot of other providers that wrap our app such as a styled-components theme provider and they would also be needed in the Algolia specific components.

Is there any way to persist the active providers of our app into this renderer?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The issue comes from the fact that this renderer uses the `render` API from React (and not [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)) so there's no access to the `RouterContext` from Next.js.

One way to solve it is to wrap the components that need to use `<Link>` with `RouterContext.Provide` from Next.js and provide it with the value of `useRouter`.

```js
// …
import { RouterContext } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/router-context';

function ProductItem({ router, href, children }) {
  return (
    <RouterContext.Provider value={router}>
      <Link href={href}>{children}</Link>
    </RouterContext.Provider>
  );
}

function App() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      getSources={() => [
        {
          // ...
          templates: {
            item({ item }) {
              return (
                <ProductItem router={router} href="path/to/page">
                  {/* … */}
                </ProductItem>
              );
            },
          },
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```

You can do the same thing with other contexts.

Full disclosure, I work on Autocomplete at Algolia and we're aware of this problem. If you want to track progress, feel free to open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete/issues) as this helps us prioritize.